# Loop of UITextfield.tag

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in iOS and I have a lot of UITextField with a tag property equal to 1.

I want a loop `for x in 1...30` for all the UITextFields `num1001`, `num1002`, `num1003`, `num1004`, `num1005`, .... Something like this: `num100x.tag=1`

How can I do a loop to make this a cleaner code?

```
num1001.tag = 1
num1002.tag = 1
num1003.tag = 1
num1004.tag = 1
num1005.tag = 1
.
.
.
```

Comment: do you name your text fields using certain naming pattern?

Comment: yes, I use a certain name pattern

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance how many UITexFields you have, you can make a for-in loop like this :

```
for index in 0...howManyUitextFields {
    num1001.tag = index
}
```

With `howManyUitextFields` equals to the total number of your UITextFields. Basically I used a for-in loop to iterate throughout the sequence going from 0 to the total number of UItextFields. (= 0...howManyUiTextFields)
Then you set the tag of your UItextField with the index.

This is only for the part to set the tag property.

1rst Edit to have dynamic variable names. You can create an empty array of UITextFields like this : `var arrayTextFields = [UITextFields]()`. Then in the for-in loop you could do something append each UITextField and the tag property :

```
for index in 0...howManyUitextFields {
    let textField = UItextField() // Init your UITextField
    textField.tag = index
    arrayTextFields.append(textField)
}
```

Then if you want to access your UITextFields you just need to use the subscript index like this `arrayTextFields[0].tag` for the first textField then `arrayTextFields[1].tag` for the second one...

Comment: I want to change num100x.tag = 1 and I want a loop for x in 1...30 for all the UITextfields num1001,num1002,num1003,num1004,num1005....

Comment: I think there is no other way than passing through an array using Swift.

Comment: thanks Arrabidas92 with an array of textfields a make it!

Comment: Alright ! Nice could you just upvote my answer or validate it to give my reward. Every work deserves a reward.